# How to convert a PromQL query in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to convert this PromQL query (from their documentation)

```
http_requests_total{job="prometheus",group="canary"}
```

In SQL but I'm not sure if I did it right:

```
SELECT * FROM http_requests_total WHERE job='prometheus' GROUP BY canary
```

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me the query should be more like:

```
SELECT * FROM http_requests_total WHERE job='prometheus' AND group = 'canary'
```